# AttributeError: module '_distutils_hack' has no attribute 'ensure_shim'

Tags: python

I am doing a project in python but i have noticed that i am suddenly getting this error out of the blue

```
F:\python\Ai\Jarvis>C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe f:/python/Ai/Jarvis/main.py
Error processing line 1 of C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\distutils-precedence.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  AttributeError: module '_distutils_hack' has no attribute 'ensure_shim'

Remainder of file ignored
```

Please help

Comment: I am getting the same error after upgrading to Linux Mint 20.3 (Una) in conjunction with installing 'Rapid Photo Downloader'. python3 -m pip list -v | grep pip
Error processing line 1 of /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/distutils-precedence.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 175, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  AttributeError: module '_distutils_hack' has no attribute 'ensure_shim'

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, for users who this this with the latest version of pip (i.e. 22.2.1)... You need to upgrade setuptools, or use an older version of pip. See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11314 for the details.

If this is on a non-disposable environment (eg: your laptop), you can upgrade setuptools by doing the following:

- Download from https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/raw/22.2/public/get-pip.py
- Run `python get-pip.py`